# Trigger OnClick in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use trigger() in jquery to emulate onclick attribute of a anchor tag:

```
<a id="anc" href="#" onclick="someFunction()"> some text </a>
```

here if i use

```
$("anc").trigger('click');
```

its not working

Comment: Read this for a better perspective http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery

Comment: i edited your question and made markup look better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to correctly reference the id "anc" in the jQuery selector with a #:

```
$("#anc").trigger('click');
```

Comment: damn forgot ! working overtime ! all sorts of things going wrong ! thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to use # for id

```
$("#anc").click(function() {
    return false // this will kill the default behaviour and your page won't jump
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when using an id you can use `('#idname').trigger('click')` , when using a class you can use `('.classname').trigger)('click')`