# Convert to Bootbox confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

The following code pops up a confirmation windows when the Delete user link is pressed:

```
<a href="delete_user.php?id=123" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete user</a>
```

In this case when the OK button is pressed the link delete_user.php?id=123 will be executed.
When the Cancel button is pressed nothing will happened.

I would like to do the same thing with Bootbox.

```
   <a class="alert" href="list_users.php?id=123">Delete user</a>

    <script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {

            if (result) {
               // What to do here?
            } else {
               // What to do here?
            }               
        });

        });
    </script>
```

What to do under if(result) and else statements?

Comment: `if (result) document.location.href = this.attr('href');`. No `else` required.

Comment: When I used this.attr('href'); I get TypeError: this.attr is not a function.

When I change to $(this).attr('href'); i get Undefined.

Any idea?

Comment: Hm... what if you just tried `this.href`?

Comment: I think the issue with @JulianH.Lam's solution is a scope issue. $(this) as the link doesn't exist in the bootbox.confirm() function. I've had a similar issue. My solution was to create a hidden button and a visible button and then in the if(result) { } call $("#hiddenbuttonID).click().

Comment: I found how to solve the problem and you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379794/jquery-click-event-preventdefault/18805115#18805115

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This worked for me. Grab the "click" href and use it when you have "result".

```
  <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
            var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
            e.preventDefault();    
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {    
                if (result) {
                    document.location.href = link;  // if result, "set" the document location       
                }    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works great!

```
$(".alert").on("click", function (e) {
    // Init
    var self = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    // Show Message        
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
        if (result) {                
            self.off("click");
            self.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Works Great