# jQuery Expander Plugin: How to hide all expanded portions when click "Read more"?

Tags: jquery, plugins, expander

I am using jQuery Expander Plugin v1.4.4 to format FAQ part on my website, and have a question how to hide all opened (expanded) portions of text (in my case answers) when you click on some  "Read more" link. I guess it should be specified in afterExpand: opton.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the code that you've used?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite interesting problem, as there doesn't seem to be collapse method provided in the api to be called explicitly.

there would be a place for call:

```
  $('XYZ').expander({
    ...
    beforeExpand: function() {
    // somehow collapse everything :)
    }
});
```

but nothing to call :)

EDIT: OK, I think it would be theoretically possible to emulate click (in javascript) on all the expanded FAQs :)
That sounds like a hack, but it could work.
You just need to find those currently open, via some selector and call: `.click()` on them.

The way to emulate mouse in javascriptwas found here ( [How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery), as reply from Stevanicus)