# Click anchor, and be brought to linked page

Tags: javascript

I have a anchor on which I trigger a `click` with JavaScript. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWQwt/).

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click();
});
```

For some reason, triggering the `click` does not bring me to the page specified by the `href` attribute of the anchor.

How can I have the `click` event also bring me to the page linked by the anchor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)

Comment: It is the same question, but the chosen answer is wrong. @Stevanicus had the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work like that, the call `$('a').click();` is a short cut for `$('a').trigger('click');` which tries to simulate a click action on the anchor element.

But the simulation is not absolute, though it will fire the registered event handler it will not completely simulate a use click trigger the default action.

As per the jquery doc for [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the
>   matched elements for the given event type.

and

> Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event.

So I don't think it is possible to completely simulate a user action and trigger a redirection using this method

Comment: `$('a').get(0).click();` gets around the trigger method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something to do with jQuery and the trigger method, works fine when you change [object object] to [object]. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWQwt/1/). Enjoy!

```
$(function() {
    $('a').get(0).click();
});
```