# MVC click on link upon page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a link click whenever the page reloads with jQuery, however this code is not working:

```
@model IEnumerable<SPMVCApp.Models.Picture>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
<h2>@ViewBag.Mb Mb</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { id = "btn" })
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#btn').click()
    })
</script>
```

I tried using $ instead of jQuery when firing the click but still no luck, I haven't got much experience with jQuery/JavaScript

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery('#btn').trigger('click')`?

Comment: Try @id = "btn" check your source with firebug or some other inspector, try debuging in javascript. I prefer also to use $("#btn").trigger("click") but that should not matter. Also your document ready does not have ;.

Comment: One important thing to do not use Html.ActionLink if you have a lot of links it will slow down your page load, but that is another subject :)

Comment: Satpal thanks, that didn't help however. @VladimirBozic, what should be used instead of ActionLink would you say?

Comment: @VladimirBozic I tried @id="btn" and using trigger and still no results. I know syntax should be proper because I tried $("btn").css("font-size", 5) and it changes the font upon load so I'm quite confused at this point.

Comment: I use Url.RouteUrl and Html.RouteLink where ever possible. ActionLink can slow down page load a lot if you have a lot of link's but not if you don't have a lot of custom routes, if you do than avoid ActionLink cause searching tru route dictionary takes time.

Comment: Further on the main problem, is there correct link on your element. You can also try calling it like this : document.location.href =  $("#btn").attr("href");

Comment: @VladimirBozic how should I connect this with the click?

Comment: You can call it from click handler $("#btn").click(function(){document.location.href = $("#btn").attr("href");});

Comment: What browser do you use for debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        document.location.href = "YourUrlFor Refresh"
    })
})
```

also do not remember that include your page to Jquery Script like 1.8.1

Comment: No need for -1 for @Leo missing semi-collons it is not syntax error, but plain simple bad code writing habit, and i did find that i can cause errors in some older browsers...

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code I understood that you want to call Create Action of your controller.
So instead of calling click event of your button you call call that action directly from your javascript using ajax.

Se bellow e.g.

```
$.get("Home/Create", function (result) {
  // do wahtever you want to do with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can debug it in console at chrome or firefox .

check whether `jQuery('#btn')` is `[]` or the elemnt you want.

Comment: this is what I get, however the site still doesn't reload [<a class=​"btn" href=​"/​Picture/​Create">​Create New​</a>​] @Loda

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it.

I just need to add [0] after the parameter as so:

$('#btn')[0].click()

or

jQuery('#btn')[0].click()