# jQuery on click a div showing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my markup like this. I want that when someone click on the div demo then it will redirect to the second anchor tag link.

```
   <div class="demo">
      <div class="social">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="icon"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="http://test.com/page" target="_blank" class="icon"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So for that I have my jquery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".demo").on('click', function () {
    var link = jQuery(this).find('li:last-child').children('a').attr("href");
    window.location.href = jQuery(link);
  });
});
```

But this one is showing error in console tab like Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: with the link . So how to solve this issue?

Comment: any reason why you have `jQuery(link)`?

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery

Comment: @Java_User is right! Why did you use link in `jQuery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `href` string you got in link variable instead of `jQuery` object, wrapping link in jQuery function consider it as variable passed selector. I think you **wont have any variable defined with the name equal to value of link(varible)**

*Change*

```
window.location.href = jQuery(link);
```

*to*

```
 window.location.href = link;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
window.location.href = jQuery(link);
```

to this:

```
window.location.href = link;
```

---

That is a variable which stored a `href` attribute value, so you don't have to wrap it with jQuery to create an object of it.