# Pressing enter on form input and changing default action (submit form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have simple form with:

- two input fields `facebook event link` and `name`
- `import details` link next to `facebook event link` input - when I clickthis, it changes it's `href` attribute from `/events/new` to `/events/new?fb_event_id={fb_event_id extracted from link}` and makes new request with this updated `href`.
- `submit` button to submit form.

http://www.bootply.com/KMfGxnrqxf

When I fill `facebook event link` input with for example: 
https://www.facebook.com/events/123 and click `import details` it all works fine - changes link to `/events/new?fb_event_id=123` and makes new request.

Now I try to do the same by pressing `enter` key instead of mouse click.
It changes `href` to the correct one, but doesn't request this new url.

Any idea why?

Comment: Instead of "$('#import').click(function() {"  try  "$('#new_event').submit(function() {"

Comment: submit doesn't work (this `import details` is link styled as button)

Comment: Try: `$('#import')[0].click();` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrm4dy3c/)

Comment: It works phillip100, can you explain me a little bit what was wrong?

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa , I found this a while ago on SO. It's about to get a DOM element instead of jQuery object - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10559680/962734 (therefore I didn't post the answer here)

Comment: @phillip100 please write an answer and I'll accept it as it's a little bit better in my case than andi's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native anchor click behavior can be triggered using this:

```
$(element)[0].click();
```

It getting the first element of the elements array (DOM element instead of jQuery object).

[Solution reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559680/962734)

Answer (score 2):

When you trigger the click event using `$('#import').click();`, that only kicks off the JS event handlers.  It does not trigger the natural event associated with that element, i.e. it will not actually redirect the page to the anchor's href.  You need to add that redirect into your JS event handler using something like:

```
window.location.href = '/events/new?fb_event_id='+event_id;
```

Comment: I added `window.location.href = $('#import').attr('href');` and it works, thanks.