# Best way to trigger link using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have the following link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetContentPage", "Home")" id="getStarted">
    <img class="img-responsive " src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
 </a>
```

All I need to do is trigger this link(which will trigger the Controller method).

I tried this `$("#getStarted").trigger("click")` but it doesn't work.

How can I trigger this link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trigger` method doesn't change url of the current tab, it executes bound event handlers. You can either use the native DOM `click` method:

```
$("#getStarted").get(0).click();
```

Or set the `href` property of the `location` object:

```
location.href = $("#getStarted").prop('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this, the link will be triggered on DOM ready :

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click','#getStarted', function(){
       window.location = $(this).attr('href');   
   });
   $('#getStarted').trigger('click');
});
```