# Simulate clicking an anchor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to trick my browser into thinking I clicked on the anchor. So when the  loads it should click the anchor (in the example below that will redirect to google.com)

```
<a class="GoogleAnchor" href="google.com">Click Me</a>

<script>

function simulateClick() {
    var a = $(".GoogleAnchor")[0];
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
}

simulateClick();

</script>
```

So far nothing happens haha.

Comment: Why not just use [a.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Because it will not trigger native click and browser will not navigate to new address.

Comment: @dfsq, is this browser dependent, as doing a `.click()` on an anchor element does a page navigation in my Chrome browser.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Are you sure? Browser should not matter, as jQuery trigger basically just triggers "own" events bound with `on` method, as far as I know. http://plnkr.co/edit/dD7Cm6BnnWeEcWAke0pM?p=preview

Comment: Your example works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6vwp3qwj/. Are you getting errors in the console? Do you need jQuery for this?

Comment: `a.click()` works fine. Isn't it working for you because you are calling `simulateClick()` before page load?

Comment: @dfsq, that sample is doing the jQuery's click event, the OP's `a` variable is the DOM element, so .click would be the DOM elements click

Comment: @dfsq difference in OP code is dom element not jQuery object

Comment: @PatrickEvans ops, of course, I though you were talking about jQuery. Native `click` works of course.

Comment: @j08691 I'm confused, your JSFiddle works but when I change the html so that the anchor goes to say google.com it doesnt work?

Comment: That's just a browser security setting (`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`)

Answer (score 5):

How about calling the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) handler on the underlying DOM element:

```
function simulateClick() {
    var a = $(".GoogleAnchor")[0];
    a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery use the [Trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
a.trigger('click', function(){
 // if you want a callback function

};)
```

or just

```
    a.trigger('click');
```

Comment: did you try this? It most defintiely doesn't work using jQuery clcik, but should using native one

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery