# Click trigger not working with anchor tag. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I want to call `trigger("click")` with id of anchor tag.
This simple demo not working. Why?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="bb.html" id="aa">Hello</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#aa").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you want to trigger click but default value is null you should update your html

Comment: <a href="bb.html" id="aa" onclick="window.location='bb.html'">Hello</a

Comment: may be you can use jquery simulate. check this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132076/3607064

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `trigger` is a jQuery function which triggers ONLY callbacks set with jQuery or natively. 
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

If you want to simulate a `click` on the `a` tag, you will have to `get` the DOM element and then call `click` function like this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="bb.html" id="aa">Hello</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#aa").get(0).click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, run into code snippet but not work into my pc.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere. Check the console for more details

Comment: Already checked. There is no error.

Comment: So, check the selector.

Comment: *"This is because `trigger` is a jQuery function which triggers ONLY callbacks set with jQuery"* No, that's incorrect; proof: https://jsfiddle.net/t9LLonn7/1/ Moreover, if it were true, there'd be no point to the [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method. The link you provided in your answer says quite clearly: *"To trigger handlers bound via jQuery without also triggering the native event, use `.triggerHandler()` instead."* So clearly `trigger` at least tries to trigger native handlers.

Comment: It's more precise but it does not change anything for the OP. Edited answer anyway.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just do a page redirect?

Comment: This is just demo code. I want to implement in other project.